# How can i add and detect qrcode on my map?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i detect and add qrcodes on my map with ros hector slam?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122821/how-can-i-add-and-detect-qrcode-on-my-map?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) provides localization and mapping capabilities and does not perform detection and tracking of QR codes. These two tasks are performed mainly by the [hector_qrcode_detection](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision/tree/master/hector_qrcode_detection) and [hector_object_tracker](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_worldmodel/tree/master/hector_object_tracker) packages. We have not released extensive documentation or tutorials for those, but launch files used on our Hector UGV robot for [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKI378kadp8) are available ([here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_worldmodel/blob/master/hector_object_tracker/launch/object_tracker.launch) and [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision/blob/master/hector_qrcode_detection/launch/qrcode_detection.launch)). See also the [Hector Open Source Modules](https://www.sim.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/publ/download/2013_RoboCup_Kohlbrecher_open_source_tools.pdf) overview paper for some high level information on which components are responsible for which task.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-26**:
How can i set input of drives (video0 or video1) for cameras using hector_qrcode_detection  ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-02-26**:
You have to remap topics as done in the qrcode_detection.launch file linked above.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-03-02**:
Thanks for your time dear Stefan, I want to detect Qr code by usb camera(/dev/video0), what i must to do?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-02**:
You have to run a camera driver that provides images via ROS topics, basics are for example described here: http://wiki.ros.org/camera_drivers

**Comment by [rahul puram](https://answers.ros.org/users/40484/rahul-puram/) on 2020-01-21**:
I have detected the QR codes with visp_auto_tracker in which the data in the QR code will be retrieved by using it.Now I want that data and coordinates to publish to mark a point in the map. What I have to modify in order to get the markers into the hector_geotiff_map.
Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [rahul puram](https://answers.ros.org/users/40484/rahul-puram/) on 2020-01-21**:
@programmer have u remapped the topic /image or /image_raw to qrcode_detection.launch file in hector_qrcode_detection file??? If done, can u just share that code for us.....
Thanks in advance

**Comment by [rahul puram](https://answers.ros.org/users/40484/rahul-puram/) on 2020-02-04**:
I have modified the code of hector_geotiff.cpp file by subscribing the qr code data and the coordinates of the detected qr code detected.Now I want to modify the geotiff_writer.cpp file in order to get the points on to the map. I dont have any idea what to do in that file.Can anyone please help me in this problem as  I have to participate in German RoboCup 2020.Thanks in advance....

**Comment by [rahul puram](https://answers.ros.org/users/40484/rahul-puram/) on 2020-03-21**:
Yeah, I finally got my markers on to the map using hector_slam. I can actually show the map but my points are less in order to upload an image. Thanks!!